# How to change my URL on intranet

Tags: permalinks

I have a WordPress blog installed on my machine. I got a strange requirement from my team but I don't know how I should implement it: blog pages should be segregated under "blog/" or a similar sub-domain.

For example: http://example.com/blog/hello-world rather than http://example.com/hello-world

How should I do this? The index page of the website is the WordPress front page.

Comment: Create static page for your blog. http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

Comment: Do you want this for individual post pages (not pages pages, archives or whatever) only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "blog" to your Permalink settings, like:

```
/blog/%post_title%/
```